# Newbie in Android development. Implement several different processes in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm begining to learn android development, and I'm trying to make an app just to learn the language and philosophy.

This app, has to show an image in the middle of the screen, a button below, and a chronometer in the right side. When the app starts, the chronometer has to begin a countdown. When the user press the button, a blur effect has to be applied to the image, and the seconds left to finish the countdown increase by 10.

I almost know how to program the blur efect to the image, the button press, and the countdown and increase by 10 whenever the button is pressed. But I'm not sure about putting all together.

As far as I know, it should be done by designing an activity, and putting inside the activity the image, the button, and another image or a set of changing images or text for the countdown clock. But as I advance in my studied, today I have read that in order to manage different actions in an activity it is neccesary to do it by using fragments. And I have found much complex programming fragments than activities.

So the question is: can I make what I'm trying to do by a simple activity and defining classes and methods for the image effect and the countdown clock or have I to make it with fragments?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you don't need to know about fragments as yet. Start by implementing a single activity.

Comment: Thank you very much. Better, because what I have read about frangments is too complex for my by now.

Answer (score 1):

> today I have read that in order to manage different actions in an activity it is neccesary to do it by using fragments

To be blunt, either you either misunderstood what you read, or you are reading the wrong material.

> can I make what I'm trying to do by a simple activity and defining classes and methods for the image effect and the countdown clock

Yes.

> have I to make it with fragments?

No. It is possible that the whole UI might be *a* fragment, particularly if it might be shown alongside something else in some cases (e.g., a tablet) and not in others (e.g., a phone). And there is nothing stopping you from making that UI using several fragments, though that would be rather unusual.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already conveyed, no need to go with fragments.. Activity wud suffice.. As far as putting it together is considered, I guess you need to learn more about layouts.. Layouts are the files which basically help you put things on UI as you want it to look like.. There are plenty of material available online for understanding layouts.. Happy learning.. :)

Comment: Also, after defining classes and methods for the image effect and the countdown clock, you can call these methods in onCreate()..